# Why does an AWS EC2 have multiple folders under /var/lib/cloud/instances/ with different instance_ids?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to debug something about `user_data` script on an AWS EC2.  I ssh'ed into the machine, I found the follow folders:

```
[root@ip-10-xx-xxx-xx instances]# pwd
/var/lib/cloud/instances
[root@ip-10-xx-xxx-xx instances]# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct 18 20:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Oct 18 20:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 18 20:30 i-0717759c86cxxxxxx
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct 18 20:31 i-0d00c6a1xxxxxxxxx
```

Why are there two different folders of different instance IDs in a single AWS EC2, and how are they related to each other?

Answer (score 3):

The **User Data field** on an Amazon EC2 instance can be used to pass data to the instance, which is then accessed via `http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/`.

This was originally just a way to pass some simple information, but it was later used by Canonical to create [cloud-init](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which can take a script from User Data and run it when the instance first starts. Or, to be more accurate, it will run the first time that the disk boots for a given **instance ID**.

This means, for example, that if Instance A is booted, the script will run. Any future boots of Instance A will not activate the script. However, if an AMI is created from the instance and another instance is launched from the AMI (Instance B), then the script *will* execute because this is the **first boot for that given instance ID**.

From [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

> When a user data script is processed, it is copied to and executed from `/var/lib/cloud/instances/instance-id/`. The script is not deleted after it is run. Be sure to delete the user data scripts from `/var/lib/cloud/instances/instance-id/` before you create an AMI from the instance. Otherwise, the script will exist in this directory on any instance launched from the AMI.